# Unhandled Exception: Invalid argument(s): Illegal argument in isolate message: (object extends NativeWrapper - Library:'dart:io' Class: )

Tags: android, ios, flutter, mobile, dart-isolates

I Using Isolate for onSelect Function  to add one list to the selected list

The exception is on the Message argument   use in this :

```
Isolate isolate = await Isolate.spawn<Map<String,dynamic>>(isolateTask, {
  "sendPort": receivePort.sendPort,
  "chatListingModel": chatListingModel.toJson(),
});
```

Exception :

ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: Invalid argument(s): Illegal argument in isolate message: (object extends NativeWrapper - Library:'dart:io' Class: _RandomAccessFileOpsImpl@13069316)
E/flutter (29801): #0      Isolate._spawnFunction (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:399:25)
E/flutter (29801): #1      Isolate.spawn (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:379:7)
E/flutter (29801): #2      HomeProvider.computeTask (package:chat_app/provider/home/home_provider.dart:1054:37)
E/flutter (29801): #3      HomeProvider.getBody.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:chat_app/provider/home/home_provider.dart:338:23)
E/flutter (29801): #4      ChatListingTile.build.<anonymous closure> (package:chat_app/views/chat_listing/widgets/chat_listing_widget.dart:76:23)
E/flutter (29801): #5      _InkResponseState.handleLongPress (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:1121:26)
E/flutter (29801): #6      GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:253:24)
E/flutter (29801): #7      LongPressGestureRecognizer._checkLongPressStart (package:flutter/src/gestures/long_press.dart:723:11)
E/flutter (29801): #8      LongPressGestureRecognizer.didExceedDeadline (package:flutter/src/gestures/long_press.dart:618:5)
E/flutter (29801): #9      PrimaryPointerGestureRecognizer.didExceedDeadlineWithEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:643:5)
E/flutter (29801): #10     PrimaryPointerGestureRecognizer.addAllowedPointer.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:586:41)
E/flutter (29801): #11     Timer._createTimer.<anonymous closure> (dart:async-patch/timer_patch.dart:18:15)
E/flutter (29801): #12     _Timer._runTimers (dart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart:398:19)
E/flutter (29801): #13     _Timer._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart:429:5)
E/flutter (29801): #14     _RawReceivePort._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:192:26)

Code :

on Select method which is need to call on Isolate,

```
  onSelect({required ChatListingModel chatListingModel, required SendPort sendPort}) {
    dev.log("selected Chat :: ${chatListingModel.toJson()}");

    // if(chatListingModel.chatRoomModel?.isGroupChat == false) {
    showDeleteInChatListing = true;

    if (chatListingModel.isSelected ?? false) {
      _selectedChatList.add(chatListingModel);
    } else {
      _selectedChatList.removeWhere((element) =>
      element.chatRoomModel?.roomId ==
          chatListingModel.chatRoomModel?.roomId);
    }

    // Create a set to store the IDs of selected chat rooms
    Set<String?> selectedChatRoomIds = _selectedChatList
        .map((selectedChat) => selectedChat.chatRoomModel?.roomId)
        .toSet();

// Update chatList based on _selectedChatList
    for (int i = 0; i < chatList.length; i++) {
      ChatListingModel currentChat = chatList[i];
      bool isSelected = selectedChatRoomIds.contains(currentChat.chatRoomModel?.roomId);
      if (currentChat.isSelected != isSelected) {
        if(showDeleteInChatListing) {
          chatList[i] = currentChat.copyWith(isSelected: isSelected);
          notifyListeners();

        }
      }
    }

    if (_selectedChatList.isNotEmpty) {
      showDeleteInChatListing = true;
    } else {
      resetDelete();
      showDeleteInChatListing = false;
    }
    sendPort.send(showDeleteInChatListing);
   // notifyListeners();
    // }
  }
```

Compute task call first time when onSelect called:

```
 Future<void> computeTask(ChatListingModel chatListingModel) async {
    ReceivePort receivePort = ReceivePort();
    Isolate isolate = await Isolate.spawn<Map<String,dynamic>>(isolateTask, {
      "sendPort": receivePort.sendPort,
      "chatListingModel": chatListingModel.toJson(),
    });

    receivePort.listen((message) {
      if (message is bool) {
        showDeleteInChatListing = message;
        notifyListeners();
      }
    });
  }

  void isolateTask(Map<String,dynamic> message) {
    print(" isolate message :: ${message}");
    ChatListingModel chatListingModel =
    ChatListingModel.fromJson(message['chatListingModel']);
    SendPort sendPort = message['sendPort'];
    onSelect(chatListingModel: chatListingModel, sendPort: sendPort);
  }
```

and From UI it call as :

```
  onSelect: ({required ChatListingModel chatListingModel}){
                      computeTask(chatListingModel);
                  },
```

Please Help me to solve this exception.